# Ruby uninitialized constant NameError

Tags: ruby, class

I have two ruby files. The first is

```
require 'www/poster'

poster = Poster.new()
```

The second ('www/poster.rb') is

```
require ...

class Poster ... end
```

The problem is, when I run the first file, I get an error:

```
in `<main>': uninitialized constant Poster (NameError)
```

**But** if I replace the original code with just

```
require ...
class Poster

end

__END__
class Poster #original class here
```

it's ok. The code worked fine in Ruby 1.8.6, problems started after upgrading to 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please post the smallest *runnable* piece of code that exhibits the behaviour you describe. Your code runs just fine here after filling in the ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing whatsoever in your code that would cause it to behave differently in Ruby 1.9 than in Ruby 1.8. And indeed, when I copy & paste the code you posted into two files, they work exactly like the are supposed to, in all of the following configurations:

- MRI Ruby 1.8.6 (2009-03-31 patchlevel 368) [i386-mingw32]
- YARV Ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mingw32]
- JRuby 1.4.0dev (ruby 1.8.7p174) (2009-08-24 6586) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_14-ea) [x86-java]
- JRuby 1.4.0dev (ruby 1.9.1p0) (2009-08-24 6586) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_14-ea) [x86-java]

Comment: well, in the erroneous '...' means some skipped code, but thanks for the efforts, in my case there was some unicode connected error that ruby interpreter didn't wan't to report for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error

```
`<class:Employee>': uninitialized constant Employee::Datamapper (NameError)
```

when compiling. Here is the code

```
class Employee
  include Datamapper::Resource
  property :id,             Serial
....
```

The reason for the error was I spelled DataMapper with a lowercase 'm'